# ember meta information seems to be shared by controllers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

meta information. index and limit is used within link-tos for pagination.

the meta information seems to be shared amongst controllers. the router is as such

```
this.resource('persons', { path: 'persons/index/:index/limit/:limit' }, function() {
 this.resource('person', { path: 'person/:person_id' }, function() {  
    this.resource('personaddresess', { path: 'personaddresess/:person_id/index/:index/limit/:limit' });
  });
```

the toplevel navigation have link-tos with index of 0 and limit of 50

```
 {{#link-to 'persons' 0 50 }}
```

the url is correct at `#/persons/index/0/limit/50`

the secondlevel navigation for addresses use index of 0 and limit of 9

```
  {{#link-to 'personaddresses' id 0 9}}
```

after 'clicking' on the above link-to the limit for BOTH persons and personaddresses is set to 9.

ie. the url is now `#/persons/index/0/limit/9/person/1/personaddresses/1/index/0/limit/9`

Both routes use the following for obtaining models from REST

```
   model: function(params) {
      var index = numeral().unformat(params.index);
      var limit = numeral().unformat(params.limit);
      return this.store.find(yaddayadda);
```

now it seems that the meta is shared amongst controllers. should each controller not have their own meta (since each have their own model)?

```
App.PersonsController =  Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  meta: function() {
     return this.get('model.meta');
  }.property('model.meta'),
});

App.PersonAddressController =  Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  meta: function() {
     return this.get('model.meta');
  }.property('model.meta'),
});
```

The meta does pass thru a extractMeta function after each find that sets the meta for each type on the store.

```
store.setMetadataFor(type, { limit: payload.limit });  // sets the metadata for "post"
```

However, neither the model type are the same (one is Person, the other is PersonAddress); moreover, the store parameters are **not** used. The hardcoded params (0,50 and 0,9) passed in link-to are used?!

not sure whether its pertinent but in sections of the 'persons' template the following is used. `{{#link-to 'persons' meta.next meta.limit }}`  however, the above behavior takes place whether this latter link-to is clicked.

there is an intermediary step that loads an individual person by id. (as seen in the above url as `person/1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this had little to do with meta, model.meta, extract meta or store meta.

the parameters have to be uniquely named whether its id, index or limit.

```
this.resource('persons', { path: 'persons/index/:personsindex/limit/:personslimit' }

this.resource('personaddresess', { path: 'personaddresess/:person_id/index/:paindex/limit/:palimit' });
  });
```

then in the route... match up those params.

```
 model: function(params) {
      var index = numeral().unformat(params.paindex); //using int but wtcmb
      var limit = numeral().unformat(params.palimit);
      return this.store.find(yaddayadda);
```

note that it seems fine to re-use the field name within the url, in this case `/index/` and `/limit/`